# All columns are not passed when we use apply on result of groupby with a custom function

Tags: python, pandas, apply, pandas-groupby

Create a DataFrame,

```
x_df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3,4,5,6], 'b': [1,2,1,2,1,2],
                     'c': ['x','x','y','y','z','z']})

Out[56]: 
   a  b  c
0  1  1  x
1  2  2  x
2  3  1  y
3  4  2  y
4  5  1  z
5  6  2  z
```

Now I want to use a function on every value of column 'c'. So I use the `apply()` function on the result of `groupby`.

```
x_df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3,4,5,6], 'b': [1,2,1,2,1,2], 'c': ['x','x','y','y','z','z']})

def fun(X):
    print("===============>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ")
    print(list(X))
    print("\n")
    c_str = X.c.tolist[0]
    print("Value of c_str ==========>>> "+ str(c_str))
    return y


x_df1 = x_df.groupby('c').apply(fun).reset_index()
```

Running above code gives the output below:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------
===============>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> 
['a', 'b', 'c']


===============>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> 
['a', 'b', 'c']


===============>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> 
**['a', 'b']**


===============>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> 
**['a', 'b']**


Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-20-6870c2554589>", line 12, in <module>
    x_df1 = x_df.groupby('c').apply(fun).reset_index()

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 930, in apply
    return self._python_apply_general(f)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 936, in _python_apply_general
    self.axis)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 2273, in apply
    res = f(group)

  File "<ipython-input-20-6870c2554589>", line 6, in fun
    c_str = X.c.tolist[0]

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 4376, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'c'
```

---

So, the in the first two calls of the function fun X has all three columns (which should be the case), but in 3rd and 4th call column `c` is missing. because of which I can't access it. Can someone guide me what wrong I am doing and why column `c` is not present on 3rd and 4th calls?

Comment: You have syntax errors all over the place in your question

Comment: Sorry for the errors,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
c_str = X.c.tolist[0]
```

[`pd.Series.tolist`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.tolist.html) is a method. To call a method use parentheses:

```
c_str = X.c.tolist()[0]
```

Also, of course, make sure you define `y`.

Comment: He also returns `y`, which comes out of nowhere.

Comment: Agree that the question is unclear.  The error also still happens with the change you suggest.  If the function call was the issue he'd be getting a `TypeError`, "function object is not subscriptable"

Comment: @user3483203, Strange, works fine for me on Pandas v0.23.0 / Python 3.6.5. You get the usual first group passed twice (because of the way `groupby` + `apply` works), but otherwise no errors.

Comment: https://repl.it/repls/ElementaryMotionlessApplicationstack  Maybe something introduced in 0.23.4

Comment: @user3483203, Try `return None` or `return 1` instead of `return y`. If `y` is defined the error dosn't occur. Some weird Pandas error handling logic there, I think.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to answer your question but first I see a few problems with your post so I'd like to point them out:

1. Your formatting is messed up and makes it very difficult to read your code.
2. Your `fun` function does NOT define the variable you are trying to return: `y`.
3. Your question does NOT explain what the initial problem is. You are asking how your code is wrong instead of the correct way to solve your problem.

According to your question, you want to use the apply function for every row in C but grouping by `c` could remove some rows. So, you can try

```
def fun(X):
    return X.c.tolist()[0]

x_df1 = x_df['c'].apply(fun)
```

But the problem can be solved in a better way. Instead of passing a grouped object you can just pass the column vector:

```
x_df1 = x_df['c'].apply(fun)
```

However, if we knew the initial problem you are trying to solve, then I would have recommend an apply lambda call:

```
x_df1 = x_df['c'].apply(lambda x: list(x))
```

I used `list()` but that should be replaced with what you are trying to do.